# Any example for Google like the Bing OpenLayers examples?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I would like to restrict zoom levels in OpenLayers for a Google Map.  A [Bing example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/bing-tiles-restrictedzoom.html) shows how to limit the extent of the Bing tiles:

```
var road3 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    name: "Road tiles with 3 zoom levels",
    type: "Road",
    key: apiKey,
    maxResolution: 76.43702827453613,
    numZoomLevels: 3
});
```

But I cannot find a Google example which does this same thing in OpenLayers.

Found [OpenLayersAndGoogleMapOverlays](http://code.google.com/p/xenia/wiki/OpenLayersAndGoogleMapOverlays) but didn't work.  I used it to build this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVGH6/) which also doesn't work.

Comment: Got it working but it's an incredible hack:

[fiddle/1](http://jsfiddle.net/EVGH6/1/)

Comment: Please post the working code as the answer, so future readers can find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pacofvf: I cleaned up the solution and it can be accessed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EVGH6/4/).  Most of the code is also pasted below:

```
var proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection( "EPSG:900913" ); //Spherical mercator used for google maps
var vegasAirport = new OpenLayers.Bounds ( -12821203.157925, 4310035.6046593, -12815126.414177, 4314851.1374406 );

var options = {
    maxExtent: vegasAirport.clone(),
    restrictedExtent : vegasAirport.clone (),
    projection : proj900913,
    displayProjection: proj900913,
    units : "m",
    controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(), new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()]
};

var map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map', options );
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("gmap",  { MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL: 15, MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL: 18 } );
gmap.RESOLUTIONS = gmap.RESOLUTIONS.slice( gmap.MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL, gmap.MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL );

gmap.maxExtent = vegasAirport.clone();
map.addLayers( [gmap] );
gmap.resolutions = gmap.RESOLUTIONS;

map.zoomToExtent( vegasAirport.clone() );

window.olMap = map;
```